# Configure subdomains in Lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, vhosts, subdomain

I can't start lighttpd if I try to add subdomains. Some error occurs without further details as soon as I try to load the config file with the following lines:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "sub.localhost" {
  server.document-root = "/var/www
}
```

The subdomain does not have an own folder. So using mod_simple_vhost won't work.

The error message:

```
● lighttpd.service - Lighttpd Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since So 2016-11-20 16:59:43 CET; 3s ago
  Process: 7568 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 26067 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -t -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 7568 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 20 16:59:43 mantra systemd[1]: Starting Lighttpd Daemon...
Nov 20 16:59:43 mantra lighttpd[26067]: 2016-11-20 16:59:43: (configfile.c.898) source: /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf lin
Nov 20 16:59:43 mantra lighttpd[26067]: 2016-11-20 16:59:43: (configfile.c.954) configfile parser failed at: ] ==
Nov 20 16:59:43 mantra systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
Nov 20 16:59:43 mantra systemd[1]: Failed to start Lighttpd Daemon.
Nov 20 16:59:43 mantra systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 20 16:59:43 mantra systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The example you posted is missing a closing double-quote at the end of the line

    `server.document-root = "/var/www"`

That might be a typo in your post, but in any case, the error message from lighttpd reports to you the line number in your lighttpd.conf on which you had an error.  Please look at that line in your lighttpd.conf and make sure the syntax is correct.

Reference: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_Configuration